# Chrome add-on (in-browser video rendering from native process)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, video-streaming, add-on, google-nativeclient

I'm working on some Chrome add-on which relies on native messaging protocol (chrome extension and native host application). The host application has a video render part. The video render sinks incoming video to the given native window which appears like a pop-up window.

So, I would like somehow to stick this pop-up video window to the Chrome window, or much better solution for me would be rendering video directly in the Chrome window from the native host application?

I considered NaCl and OpenCV, named pipe, shared memory and tried to make some proof of concept but with no success.

Is there any suitable solution, is this feasible?

Please suggest any other approach.

Thanks in advance!